# If $R$ is a finite boolean ring then $R \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \dots \times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $R$ is a finite boolean ring then $R \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \dots \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

So this makes sense for a lot for some obvious reasons, and I feel like I could exhibit an isomorphism by defining a map by having the $ith$ element of $R$ make the $ith$ tuple a one instead of a zero, etc. It seems strange though that this isomorphism suggests a certain linear independence of the elements of $R$, can somebody give me some insight into this phenomonon? Thanks!

Comment: What are the operations in a boolean ring?

Comment: @Wuestenfux A [boolean ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring) is a ring (with unit) in which every element is idempotent ($x^2 = x$).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** If $R$ is a boleean ring, then $\{ 0,1 \}$ is a subring which is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$. Show that $R$ becomes a vector space over $\mathbb Z_2$.

**Simpler approach** If $R \neq \{ 0,1 \}$ then for each $x \in R \backslash \{ 0, 1 \}$ you have 
$$R= Rx \oplus R(1-x)$$

Now each of these are boolean rings (the units are $x$ and $1-x$ respectively) which are smaller than $R$, use strong induction.

Comment: So to do this would I show that if $a_1x_1 + \dots + a_nx_n=0$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x_i \in R$ then $a_i=0 \forall i$? I'm having trouble doing this, care to help?

Comment: @MichaelVaughan if $R$ is any ring and $k$ is a subfield of $R$, then you can check with the axioms that $R$ is a vector space over $k$. Then, you simply USE the fact that every vector space has a basis, you don't need to prove linear independence.

Comment: how do we know that the basis is finite dimensional without knowing linear independence though? 

Like.... idk given $\{x_i\}$ an enumeration of the elements of the Boolean ring $R$, how come $x_1 + x_2$ seems like it should equal some $x_i$, yet when I look at the isomorphism i'm trying to prove it seems like all these elements are linearly independent and you can't get to one of them from a linear combination of the others.

Comment: @MichaelVaughan First, since $R$ is finite, any basis $B$ is finite. Second, you seem to believe that $R$ is the basis, but this is obviously not true. Instead, you should attempt to do the following: Since $R$ is a vector space over $\mathbb Z_2$ then it has some basis $B$. Next, since $B \subset R$ and $R$ is finite then $B$ is finite. Let $B=\{x_1,..,x_n \}$, then $$a_1x_1+....+a_nx_n \leftrightarrow (a_1,...,a_n)$$ is the isomorphism. Note that since $B$ is a basis, it is by definition linearly independent.

Comment: Ah yes, for some reason I was thinking $R$ was the basis.
Thanks for being patient with me. For some reason this result still surprises me, like I understand each theorem that leads to the result but for some reason it's still strange. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelVaughan also be careful about the following: while you got the isomorphism, it is a vector space isomorphism. You need to use the fact that $R$ is boolean to deduce that you get a ring isomorphism.... If you cannot prove directly this, show instead that if $x$ is any element in $R$ then  $R=(Rx)\oplus (R(1-x))$. This relation holds for all idempotent elements in all rings.... Then use induction on $|R|=2^n$.

Comment: Ah man, you lost me here, i'll think about it more i guess.

Comment: so you're saying $Rx \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$? why is this?

Comment: @MichaelVaughan No. I am saying that $Rx$ and $R(1-x)$ are smaller boleean rings...So you can apply the inductive assumption..

Comment: ooooh wow! Induction is so fricken' magic sometimes